# iOS TableViewCell Not Filling Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cell.  The cell is not filling the entire width, as seen by the photo below.  I have created the custom cell using IB and NIB file.  I just dragged a UITableViewCell, added my labels and all.  It uses AutoLayout, and I even have the far right label pinned to the right edge for trailing, but still it clips it off.

[image]

Comment: Can you post any code related to this table view?

Comment: My first thought would be an issue w/ the constraints; are you using Storyboard?  If so, can you send a screenshot w/ this view's constraints?

Comment: I am using IB not storyboard though. The table view fills everything up, just not the cell

Comment: @user717452 Double check does the `UITableView` have all needed constraints (especially that its right side is pinned to the superview). Looks like that you're running the app on wider display than you'd used in the IB.

Comment: @user717452 - so you're building and instantiating the view from code?  How are you setting the frame size?